# How to decode transaction log data

Tags: python, logging, transactions, web3py

With Python, how can I decode the topics from an Ethereum transaction log?

```
rec = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x034...').logs #reading the logs of a transaction
rec[4]["topics"]
```

Getting HexBytes, how to convert that into a human readable format?

```
[HexBytes('0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'),
 HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000009840d8a48692e4e0534f2c5f85f56c2cb5989aaf'),
 HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000000000a26b00c1f0df003000390027140000faa719')]
```

[image]

I tried this but it did not work

```
abi.decode(['address', 'address', 'uint256'], ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

To decode the topics from an Ethereum transaction log in Python, you can use the `decode_topic()` function from the `web3` library. Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3()

rec = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x034...').logs
topics = rec[4]["topics"]

for topic in topics:
    decoded = w3.codec.decode_topic(topic)
    print(decoded)
```

This should output a human-readable representation of each topic. The exact output will depend on the specific smart contract event that generated the log, but it should give you a good starting point to work with.